# One CSS file doesn't show same results on multiple HTML pages

Tags: html, css

I have three HTML files linked to one CSS file. Navigation styles in these HTML files are set exactly same. In one of these three files, the style is not the same as in the other ones. I don't know why it's happening. I set the CSS of header exactly same.

Here is the slight difference between them.

[image: image of "Home" header]

[image: image of "Team" header]

This is the **Home** HTML and CSS:

```css
body {
  margin: 2%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  background-image: url("../images/d.jpg");
  /*background-color: blanchedalmond;*/
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

nav>a {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-family: "Arial Narrow", sans-serif;
  margin: 7%;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-align: center;
}

nav .active {
  background-color: #ce6153;
}
```

```html
<!-- Header in "Home" file -->

<header>
  <h1>Ultimate Frisbee</h1>
  <nav>
    <a href="cssassignment.html" class="active">home</a>
    <a href="team.html">team</a>
    <a href="history.html">history</a>
    <a href="http://www.usaultimate.org/index.html">USA ultimate</a>
  </nav>
</header>

<!-- Header in "Team" file -->

<header>
  <h1>Ultimate Frisbee</h1>
  <nav>
    <a href="cssassignment.html">home</a>
    <a href="team.html" class="active">team</a>
    <a href="history.html">history</a>
    <a href="http://www.usaultimate.org/index.html">USA ultimate</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: make sure that you used same classes/elements/id's on all three pages

Comment: You need to give us two working snippets with the two different results you're obtaining.

Comment: You probably have set a padding on the body or container of the page in which it shows a slight difference in the navbar.

Comment: In your question, these two headers give same result.